# one div to wrap once it butts up against another div and not stack on it

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I can make the blue div wrap text once it butts up against the yellow div instead of stacking on top of the yellow one? Is there a way I can use overflow or wordwrap? that will make this work?

[blue div to wrap once it butts up against yellow div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42sj6.png)

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  border: px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.container div {}

.wrap1 {
  display: table;
 border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap2 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.container .learn {
  float: right;border: 1px solid yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.container .content {
  display: table;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">How do we shop our carriers to find you the best price when we have so many?</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->
  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
     <p> We use what is called a Comparative Rater. We simply input your information
which then gets sent out to all the carriers and within a minute they return their
prices. From there we choose the best one for you similar to shopping online for
flights and hotels.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use flexbox!

Add `display: flex;` to your containers. This will wrap your text once it reaches the other div. I've included a snippet example that should work for you.

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  border: px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.container div {}

.wrap1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
 border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap2 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.container .learn {
  float: right;border: 1px solid yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.container .content {
  display: table;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">How do we shop our carriers to find you the best price when we have so many?</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->
  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
     <p> We use what is called a Comparative Rater. We simply input your information
which then gets sent out to all the carriers and within a minute they return their
prices. From there we choose the best one for you similar to shopping online for
flights and hotels.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Comment: had to add text align left to it and add min width to the yellow box but it does work now.

Answer (score 0):

You could put display: flex; onto the wrap1 class instead of display table and I believe this will get the effect you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Set a percentage width on the div and then use word-wrap: break-word;

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  border: px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.container div {}

.wrap1 {
  display: table;
 border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap2 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 50%;
}

.container .learn {
  float: right;border: 1px solid yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.container .content {
  display: table;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">How do we shop our carriers to find yfkasjldkfjl;kjsdfl;kjsdfasdfasdfou the best price when we have so many?</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->
  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
     <p> We use what is called a Comparative Rater. We simply input your information
which then gets sent out to all the carriers and within a minute they return their
prices. From there we choose the best one for you similar to shopping online for
flights and hotels.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.container {
  width: 60%; /* for demo */
  margin:auto;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.container div {}

.wrap1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.title {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue
}

.container .learn {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">How do we shop our carriers to find you the best price when we have so many?</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>

</div>
<!--container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really clean solution, I'd recommend using flex-box! Elements defined within the flex boxed container will have to share the given width amongst themselves based on their needs (how much content is within them).

I like adding a min-width to the small element so it doesn't get squashed.

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  border: 5px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.wrap1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrap2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.learn {
  min-width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I would suggest staying away from floats as much as possible. It takes the element out of it's traditional flow and can cause other problems when styling.Another solution is to use `display: inline-block` - if child elements don't take up the full width of their parent's container, they will share the space. A bit wonky with 75%/24%, which is why I prefer flex-box.

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  border: 5px solid #d3d3d3;
  box-sizing: content-block;
}

.wrap1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.learn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```